# Are doctoral dissertations still permitted to be given in Latin at any of the Pontifical Universities at Rome?

Tags: contemporary-latin, academic-latin

Are doctoral dissertations still permitted to be spoken in Latin at any of the [Pontifical Universities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontifical_university) in or around Rome?

Comment: This is about the customs for when and where Latin is spoken, so I believe it's on topic.

Comment: Erkki Palmén's dissertation *De adverbiis pronominalibus localibus Latinis studia semantica et syntactica* about Latin was defended in Latin on November 28, 1998, at the University of Jyväskylä. As far as I know, this was the last Latin dissertation in Finland and the first one for almost 70 years. I believe Latin is still allowed in dissertations in Finland if there are people to do it. There are not pontifical universities in Finland.

Comment: Do you mean dissertation or disputation?

Comment: @fdb I am interested  in the dissertation or thesis at the academic level and not the disputation of the thesis involved, although that would be an interesting point to know also!

Comment: A "dissertation" is a written thesis. A "disputation" is the oral defense of the thesis. In Britain we call it a "viva".

Comment: @fdb That is my understanding of the question also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vatican Latinist [Fr. Daniel Gallagher](http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2014/03/27/priest-translates-pope-tweets-latin/6954991/), whom I met several years ago at event sponsored by [SALVI](http://www.latin.org/), told me then that he was working on a dissertation in Latin. This dissertation was for a doctorate in philosophy at the Pontifical Gregorian University. So apparently at least one of the Pontifical Universities still accepts Latin dissertations.